What are the different fasts that are considered compulsory or must follow for men? Just like Karvachauth is for women
I want to understand what are the fasts that are considered compulsory or very important for men (married men) in hinduism. Just the way a married women is expected to keep so many fasts like Karvachauth, Teej etc etc.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
